# detect encoding of id3v2 tags of mp3 file

Tags: unix, id3

I am trying to detect encoding of tags.
Using `eyeD3 file.mp3`  outputs information about file however my c++ program prints unreadable garbage as title for some mp3 file which i assume is due to encoding.

Is there a way how to find encoding of tag?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [standard (section 4.2.2)](http://id3.org/id3v2-00):

Textual frames are marked with an encoding byte.

- $00 – ISO-8859-1 (LATIN-1, Identical to ASCII for values smaller than 0x80).
- $01 – UCS-2 (UTF-16 encoded Unicode with BOM), in ID3v2.2 and ID3v2.3.
- $02 – UTF-16BE encoded Unicode without BOM, in ID3v2.4.
- $03 – UTF-8 encoded Unicode, in ID3v2.4.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mid3v2](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/man/mid3v2.html), which comes with [Mutagen](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

On Debian-based systems like Ubuntu etc., install it with

```
sudo apt install python3-mutagen
```

To list the tags with their encoding:

```
mid3v2 --list-raw "$Your_File"
```

To avoid listing a hexdump of embedded pictures etc., you can limit the output to text fields only by piping through `grep`

```
mid3v2 --list-raw "$Your_File" | grep '^T'
```